# Write regex patterns for matching single digit or double digit where tens place value is 2 or 4

Tags: regex

Below is my regex  for matching 2 digit where tens place value is 2 or 3 and it is working fine.

`^(?=[2,4])\d{1,2}$`

As soon as I add the regex for matching single digit in above regex , It started matching single digit and as well all 2 digit number.

`^(?=\d|[2,4])\d{1,2}$`

I want below sample input to be matched.

```
0
1
2 
3
24 
44
48
29
28
```

Below not to be matched.

```
99
11
33
55
77
```

Also It will great help if I would get to  know why my regex is not working.

Comment: `^[2,4]?[0-9]$` - optional `2` or `4` for tens followed any digit for units

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , It is working fine now. would you please  suggest why my regex was not working.

Comment: @novice `(?=[2,4])` is a positive lookahead (at that position it should be a look behind). Look arounds do not 'consume' the pattern. Meaning that `[2,4]` is only used to search and will not be included in a match.

Comment: @novice: in case of `^(?=[2,4])\d{1,2}$` pattern, `3` is a counter example: look ahead `(?=[2,4])` fails to match `2` or `4`, that's why `3` doesn't match.

Comment: @novide: `^(?=\d|[2,4])\d{1,2}$` matches too many texts: actually it maches *any* one or two digits numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a difference in matches as the positive lookahead asserts that there must be to the right what you specify. In there first pattern that is either `2` `4` or `,` and in the second case just a single digit.

You don't have a comma in your example data, so in that case you can match an optional 2 or 4 using just `[24]?` followed by a digit without any lookarounds.

```
^[24]?\d$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V048GM/1).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
^[2,4]?[0-9]$
```

pattern; where

```
^      - anchor, start of the text
[2,4]? - optional 2 or 4 digit for tens
[0-9]  - mandatory digit 0..9 for units
$      - anchor, end of the text
```

**Edit:** Now, let's have a look at your current patterns; the *first* is

```
^(?=[2,4])\d{1,2}$
```

Here

```
(?=[2,4]) - look ahead for 2 or 4
\d{1,2}   - one or two digits
```

as we can see `3` *doesn't match*: look ahead *fails* to find `2` or `4`. As for your *second* attempt

```
^(?=\d|[2,4])\d{1,2}$
```

pattern, where

```
 (?=\d|[2,4]) - look ahead for ANY digit (note, that |[2,4] is redundant)
 \d{1,2}      - one or two digits
```

the pattern matches *too many* texts; technically it matches any one or two digit numbers, e.g. for:

```
 79
```

we have

```
 (?=\d|[2,4]) - look ahead - succeeds with 7
 \d{1,2}      - one or two digits - succeeds with 79
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^(\d|[2,4]\d)$`

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/aZo7fK/1

```
^(\d|[2,4]\d)$

^            matches the start of string
(\d|[2,4]\d) matches either a single digit(0-9) or a two digit number which starts with either 2 or 4
$            matches the end of the string
```

- This matches either a single digit(0-9) number or a two digit number which starts with either 2 or 4.